# Using Pandas to join two csv only on same id

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So I have two csv: call the first one 'test1.csv'

```
+---------+---+---+--+
| user_id | A | B |  |
+---------+---+---+--+
|       1 | a | f |  |
|       2 | b | g |  |
|       3 | c | h |  |
|       4 | d | i |  |
|       5 | e | j |  |
+---------+---+---+--+
```

the second one is 'test2.csv'

```
+---------+---+---+--+--+
| user_id | C | D |  |  |
+---------+---+---+--+--+
|       1 | k | r |  |  |
|       2 | l | s |  |  |
|       4 | m | t |  |  |
|       5 | n | u |  |  |
|       6 | o | v |  |  |
|       7 | p | w |  |  |
|       8 | q | x |  |  |
+---------+---+---+--+--+
```

*note that not all the id in test1.csv are in test2.csv and vice versa and not ordered

desired output:

```
+---------+---+---+---+-----+
| user_id | A | B | C |   D |
+---------+---+---+---+-----+
|       1 | a | f | k | r   |
|       2 | b | g | l | s   |
|       4 | d | i | m | t   |
|       5 | e | j | n | u   |
+---------+---+---+---+-----+
```

So in essence, i want to merge the pd on user_id and not track the extraneous id

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: You've only provided test2 and the expected result but not test1?

Comment: can you see it now?

Comment: We generally discourage images or links to images because it makes it harder to copy paste data. Please include all the data as text in the question. Reference: [ask]

Comment: i think that should be better :)

Comment: @Charizard1702 See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples for best practices when asking pandas questions.

Comment: you can use `pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['user_id'], how='left')`.